# Issues with Error in duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed when I have no duplicate row names

Tags: r, csv, chi-squared

I have been analyzing my data using Chi-squared in RStudio perfectly fine until this table:
[image]

For some reason after inputing `dataframe1 = read.csv(file.choose(), row.names=1)`
which has worked perfectly fine for all my other data I get this error

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote,
>   :  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

I then tried `dataframe1 = read.csv(file.choose(), row.names=NULL)`

but then this occurred:

[image]

It added rows that were not there and put `NA` which means I can not run Chi-squared

Any thoughts on what the issue is?

Comment: I'd say it's because the two rows at the bottom are filled with missing values. Same for the column on the right of column 6. (I mean in the CSV)

Comment: You can check it: are there two rows with only commas at the end of your CSV? And one unnecessary comma at the end of each row?

Comment: It finally worked but all I did was create a new workbook and copy the table over. Very odd but maybe there was hidden data on that page that was affecting the CSV file?

Comment: Yes something like that.